# Symbol (ampersand) to html codes in php

Tags: php, html, symbols

I have variable in php $description = "Gun Stock Sealer & Filler".

How can I 'echo':

```
"Gun Stock Sealer &amp; Filler"
```

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) didn't help

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It is missing a [mcve]. echoing it should "just work". `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't make a difference (the ampersand is followed by a space, so encoding it is optional). What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Quentin He wants to display the " & a m p ;", didn't show in the first version of the post

Comment: … then `htmlspecialchars` should solve the problem. A [mcve] and a **clear problem statement** are required.

Comment: @Quentin Might have a problem in his code, let's wait for Navruz to add it to the post ! :)

Comment: I want to get string "Gun Stock Sealer &amp; Filler" from string "Gun Stock Sealer & Filler"

Comment: @Navruz  — That's what `htmlspecialchars` does.

Comment: I've tried: 
$description = htmlspecialchars("Gun Stock Sealer & Filler");
echo $description;
It prints: Gun Stock Sealer & Filler

Comment: @Navruz — https://i.imgur.com/5q1AwpT.png — Works perfectly.

Comment: Where are you running this and what version of PHP are you using? It should work fine. It fails for me at http://phpfiddle.org but works as it should at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f1c3d6c6920dfcbbf8ab3f863b8fdce2f7f8365

Comment: Personally, I think this is just an encoding issue.

Comment: On my command prompt. PHP 7.1.14. Not that that matters since every version of PHP is consistent for that. It works perfectly when I test it in PHP Fiddle: https://i.imgur.com/RNb7dHw.png

Comment: In my OpenServer there is Php-5.4. Also I've tried in http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: @Quentin I was actually asking the OP my questions but it's interesting to me that when I inspect the DOM on phpfiddle I see `&` but looking at the network tab I see `&amp;`, however on onlinephpfunctions.com the same DOM inspection shows `&amp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` takes a string of plain text and converts it to HTML source code representing the same thing.

If you output it into a webpage, the HTML source code will be parsed and the text it represents will be rendered on the page.

So if you have a PHP script which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<p>
<?php
    $description = htmlspecialchars("Gun Stock Sealer & Filler");
    echo $description;
```

Then you will generate HTML source code which includes `Gun Stock Sealer &amp; Filler`.

If you look at the webpage using a web browser, then the HTML source code will be converted to a DOM and `Gun Stock Sealer & Filler` will be rendered in the page itself.

If you want to see `&amp;` in the page itself, then you need to use `htmlspecialchars` twice.

Once to convert the plain text string to HTML source code which represents the plain text.

Then again to convert the HTML source code to different HTML source code which represents the first set of HTML source code.